# LDAP Authentication on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, ldap

In a current project I would like to check if the user is the user it says he is (no private data involved). That project is mainly about Timetables at my university. As we have a LDAP Server and every Student has an account, i would like to  authenticate against the LDAP Server but the System.DirectoryServices Assembly is not available on Windows Phone. 
Does anyone have an idea how to realise the login expect for a workaround via a Webservice? WCF would not be an option, I could theoretically send the data to a Webservice and do the authentication via PHP but I would like to keep that functionality in the app.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you create a web service in PHP and POST data to it from the app?

Comment: If the authentication is done only in the app on the phone does that mean the actual server side data service is open and has no authentication? Or that the application will use static credentials built into it? Because this is extremely insecure. Authentication should be done on the server side away from the possibility or tampering.

If however you will be connecting to a database server or similar using the user's provided credentials then why check them at all? Let the server do it.

Comment: Did you ever have any luck on this?  I am interested in doing the same thing.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTful Web service would do what you want.

Have a web server running tomcat/windows IIS (depending on how you wish to implement it)

send request to the web service via HTTPS and then have the web server connect to the LDAP server to query it.

Comment: That is the way I am currently doing it but I wanted to make the Login on the Client side not via a Webservice :/

Comment: Why not authenticate against the Database. and depending on what Database you're authenticating against i believe you can have them authenticate against LDAP.

Comment: Because I do not have a Database available (expect for the LDAP) The app I am currently developing is consuming a Webserivce Provided by my University. To validate the usernames I would thus like to log them in via LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a 3rd party library like Novell's (http://www.novell.com/developer/ndk/ldap_libraries_for_c_sharp.html)? It comes with source and MIT license.

Comment: Yes, I have tried several NuGet Packages as well as thrid party librarys. They would all work on a Desktop (WPF / Winforms) Application but not on a Silverlight (WP) App.

Comment: That's unfortunate. However, Novell's library comes with source and from what I understand it deals with sockets directly. There may be some data structures missing but that should be trivial to fix, although this might actually be more work than writing a webservice.